# Paragraph Indentation in LaTeX

Tags: indentation

I need my paragraph to be indented, but not after the section. The remaining paragraph needs to be indented. Please check the image.

[image: Latex for Paragraph Indentation]

Comment: That's the standard behaviour: are you using a document class or package that changes it?

Comment: please make a small one-page document that shows the wrong indentation and add it to your question as a text block (`{}` button in the editor)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Are you talking about indentation of the input you have shown in the picture? It will not translate to the output at all.

Comment: Right now i am doing it manually, like adding " \noindent " and "\indent" to each and every paragraph. How to automate that. 
using the following packages 
`\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}`

Comment: To start with, remove  \usepackage{indentfirst}`. It indents the first paragraph, you don't want that. Indentation for other paragraphs is the default, if that is happening in your document, your code is responisble. But we don't have that.

Comment: As Joseph mentions the image shows the normal behaviour, there is no need to indent the first paragraph after a sectional header as the sectional header already indicate something new has started. As for what ever else is going on in your document: show us code, we've run out of crystal balls and magic spells.

Comment: you should never need `\indent` and only rarely (preferably never) use `\noindnent`. The _only_ thing that `indentfirst` package does is to change the default behaviour and force the first paragraph of each section to be indented.

Comment: One addition to previous comments:  You need either `\par` or a blank line between the first and second paragraphs.  As shown, they will just run together when processed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I agree with your point that `indentfirst` packages makes the indent. That package only allows me to use of `noindent and indent` command. If i use only `\setlength` it applys to all para

Comment: sorry I don't understand that comment,  indentfirst doesn't allow or disallow the use of `\noindent` or `\indent`, but in any case, if a latex document is using `\indent` anywhere than something is wrong.

Comment: okie. Thanks @DavidCarlisle let me recheck my entire document. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no information in the question, but answering the issue as stated by the OP in comments under the question...

The default behaviour in most document classes (all the standard ones) is not to indent the first paragraph of a section. The `indentfirst` package suppresses that and forces the indentation of the first section. As the default behaviour is desired here, the solution is simply not to load `indentfirst`.